# How can I make the 'delete' key immediately delete faces instead of displaying the 'delete' menu?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I'm a beginner in blender. I want to delete a face, but pressing the <kbd>X</kbd> to delete the face brings up a menu like this:

[image]

I do not want to display the menu and delete the face each time I press <kbd>X</kbd>, I want to delete the selection as soon as I press <kbd>X</kbd>.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As Jonathan said below, you cannot avoid that menu, but doing the
>   specific selection of faces may help you out.

**There are two ways:**
Selection by <kbd>C</kbd>:
Press <kbd>C</kbd> to make easier selection of faces you want to delete by clicking and moving mouse on the faces and delete Faces, you can change the size of the selection cursor by scrolling in and out middle mouse button. You can also **Deselect** incorrect selection by pressing middle mouse.

> **Revise:**
> Press <kbd>C</kbd> and:
>  Left click and Drag to
>   **Select**.
>  Middle Click and Drag to
>   **Deselect**.

---

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left-Click</kbd>:
It can also be done by <kbd>Shift</kbd> and clicking the faces to make selection.

Delete all the selection with only one click and your are done.

Comment: They know how to delete, they want to avoid seeing the menu every time.

Comment: @RayMairlot Yes, but the question was just about saving time, no matter how, and this the way they can do it. Is my answer not related to the question?

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific way to change that. The delete menu is important, because blender needs to know what part of your selction you want to delete, because there is a huge difference between deleting only the face and deleting all selected vertices.